# Konsole page up/down keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, konsole

In CentOS 4.6, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> browses half-page up and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ `mouse wheel up` is one-page up. Is there a keyboard shortcut to do a one-page up? How would I set <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to browse one-page up?

Answer (score 3):

This is in the profile settings:

menu bar -> Settings -> Edit Current Profile... -> 'Scrolling' tab -> Scroll Page Up/Down Amount -> Full Page Height